# Why can a matlab table variable be changed using the old value, but a cell string can not?

Tags: matlab

I can rename a matlab `table` variable using its current value. E.g. with a  table `x` this works ok:

```
x.Properties.VariableNames{'Value'} = 'New_Variable_Name';    % this works
```

So why doesn't the same thing work with a cell array of strings?

```
y = {'aa', 'bb'}; 
y{'bb'} = 'cc';    % this does not work

The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.
```

What is the reason? The two objects appear to have (or at least, return) the same class (`cell`).

```
>> class(x.Properties.VariableNames)

ans =

cell

>> class(y)

ans = 

cell
```

Is this behaviour specific to matlab `table`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is specific to tables. It doesn't work on cell arrays because they are indexed with a numeric index from `1` to `numel(cellstr)` rather than by their values.

To see why it might be a problem to index by values, consider what you would expect to happen in the following case -

```
y = {'a', 'b', 'b'};
y{'b'} = 'c';
```

Do you expect `{'a', 'c', 'c'}` or `{'a', 'c', 'b'}` to be the result?

Note that if you want behaviour like this, you can do the string comparison manually -

```
>> y = {'aa', 'bb'};
>> y{ strcmp(y, 'bb') } = 'cc';
>> y
y =
    'aa'   'cc'
```

or, if you want to update multiple values simultaneously,

```
>> y = {'aa', 'bb', 'bb'};
>> y( strcmp(y, 'bb') ) = {'cc'};
>> y
y =
    'aa'   'cc'   'cc'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer lies within matlab.internal.table.parseArg, which is used in table.m. when you say:

```
x.Properties.VariableNames{'Value'} = 'New_Variable_Name';
```

A string comparison is ran on Value. I believe this is used to find the index of Value in VariableNames, enabling you to set the element to New_Variable_Name.